# Prevent AngularJS route to load view if receives 403 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm creating a permission back-end code that, whenever the user tries to access an specific page, I'll check its permissions and, if they don't have the properly permissions, I would return a 403 error in a JSON result.

The following will show how the proccess will work:

1. I have a route that handles the page access:
   [image]
2. This route will look to a ASP.NET MVC page that returns a ViewResult - a view - to AngularJS:
   [image]
3. The View action has an attribute to verify the authentication of the user and, if the user doesn't have the properly permissions, I'll return a 403 JSON response instead a View:
   [image]
4. I also created an interceptor that handles a response error - in this case the response will throw a 403 error -, so I can redirect the user to the login page instead:
   [image]

The steps are working fine and it's redirecting to the login when I get a 403 error. However, I'm also getting some strange error on the console (don't worry about the GET route name, it's correct):
[image]

It seems that the AngularJS continues the promise flow instead stop it when I intercept the 403 error. Is there a way to prevent this to occur? I mean, stop the flow after I get the 403 error and just foward the user to another route, same as I'm doing now?

Thank you all!

Comment: use non minified version of angular for more verbose error and stack trace output while developing

Comment: Even using a unminified version I'm getting the same error, @charlietfl